# Can I have the Shipping Same as Billing default to unchecked?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, shipping, checkout

I am using Expresso Store V1 and I would like the Shipping Same as Billing to default to unticked. Is this possible?

Form html:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
            <label for="shipping_same_as_billing" class="checkbox">
                {field:shipping_same_as_billing} Same as Billing Details
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#shipping_same_as_billing').change(function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('#shipping_details_drawer').slideUp();
                } else {
                    $('#shipping_details_drawer').slideDown();
                }
            });
            if ($('#shipping_same_as_billing').is(':checked')) {
                $('#shipping_details_drawer').hide();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As example from the [Docs](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/v1/checkout_tag.html#shipping_same_as_billing), don't use the default tag, but the actual rendered html:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label for="shipping_same_as_billing" class="checkbox">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping_same_as_billing" value="0" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="shipping_same_as_billing" name="shipping_same_as_billing" value="0" {shipping_same_as_billing_checked} />
  Same as Billing Details
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have to have the hidden one, so when the checkbox is unchecked it still sends a value with the form. So the second input (the checkbox one) has the default value of 0 so unchecked by default.